# Swing animation not working

Tags: java, swing, animation, intellij-idea

So, for a personal project, I've been trying to create a program in Java that can make a rudimentary animation appear on a Swing application. As far as I know, I've done everything right, and as far as I know it's working, but when I run the application, it does not let me close the application without Task Manager, and when I force quit the app IntelliJ tells me "process finished with exit code 1". It's also not displaying my animation on the screen despite displaying normal Graphics things such as lines.

Here is my JFrame code:

```
package animtest;

import javax.swing.*;

public class AnimTest extends JFrame {

    public void addComponents() {
        AnimPanel panel = new AnimPanel();
        setContentPane(panel);
    }

    public AnimTest(String string) {
        super(string);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimTest frame = new AnimTest("Animation Test");

        frame.addComponents();
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Here is my JPanel code:

```
package animtest;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class AnimPanel extends JPanel {

    Image[] marsExploding = new Image[3];

    public AnimPanel() {
        try {
            marsExploding[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("res/MarsExploding.png"));
            marsExploding[1] = ImageIO.read(new File("res/MarsExploding2.png"));
            marsExploding[2] = ImageIO.read(new File("res/MarsExploding3.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2.create();
        g.setColor(Color.white);

        for (int i = 0; i < marsExploding.length; i++) {
            g.drawImage(marsExploding[i], (getWidth() / 2) - 128, (getHeight() / 2) - 128, 256, 256, null);

            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        g.dispose();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT 1**

OK, so this is my new panel code, which should honor Swing's contract and concurrency:

```
package animtest;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class AnimPanel extends JPanel {

    Image[] marsExploding = new Image[3];

    Graphics2D g;

    int currentFrame = 0;

    public AnimPanel() {
        try {
            marsExploding[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("res/MarsExploding.png"));
            marsExploding[1] = ImageIO.read(new File("res/MarsExploding2.png"));
            marsExploding[2] = ImageIO.read(new File("res/MarsExploding3.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer(500, null);
        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                displayNewFrame(currentFrame);

                if (currentFrame < 2) {
                    currentFrame++;
                } else {
                    currentFrame = 0;
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2) {
        super.paintComponent(g2);

        g = (Graphics2D) g2.create();
    }

    public void displayNewFrame(int frame) {
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.drawImage(marsExploding[frame], (getWidth() / 2) - 128, (getHeight() / 2) - 128, 256, 256, null);
    }

}
```

However this doesn't actually display anything to the screen.

Comment: *"As far as I know, I've done everything right"* - `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(500);` isn't right. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for why and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a way to fix it

Comment: You've broken the contract of the paint chain by not calling `paintComponent`'s `super` method.  Also, don't call `repaint` from within any `paint` method, this is going to cause you no end of issues and rob you of the ability to control the timing of the animation

Comment: OK, thank you. Should I simply use `Thread.sleep(500);` instead?

Comment: Thanks, but how should I call `repaint` instead?

Comment: *"OK, thank you. Should I simply use Thread.sleep(500); instead?"* - No, that's the same thing you've done before.  Read the supplied links as they will provide you with the information you need know and understand in order to achieve what you trying to do

Comment: In you `ActionListener` for the `Timer`, call `repaint` instead of calling `displayNewFrame`, call this from your `paintComponent` method.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing

Comment: OK, that worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out ;)

Comment: Super thanks to you! Any ideas on how I could better my question for next time as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded framework, this means, that any call which is long running or blocking made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread will prevent the UI from been updated or allow the user to interact with it, making your UI appear as if it's hung (because it essentially has).

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Instead of trying to use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(500);` inside a `paint` method, you should have some background thread which ticks at a regular interval and allows you to update the UI accordingly.  The problem is, Swing is also not thread safe, meaning that you should never try and create or update the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

For a basic solution, you can, however, use a Swing `Timer`, which will trigger a `ActionListener` on a regular bases within the context of the EDT, making it safe to use with the UI.

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

Painting in Swing is performed by a series of chained method calls, custom painting requires you to insert your code within on of these links, `paintComponent` been the most preferred.

However, you are expected to honor the contract of these links by calling the `super` paint method you are overriding.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details